# using textchange event to add/subtract from a textbox

Tags: c#, winforms, math, textbox

I have 6 text boxes 2 for each type of bill that needs to be paid:

[image]

If I type a number into one of the two it updates the other with the difference:
[image]

The textboxes within the panels will always add to the same sum, if you change the value it automatically changes the value of its adjacent textbox, but the RENT textboxes are different.

I am trying to make it so the RENT textboxes take the (difference / 2) between the 3 pairs of other textboxes. so if patti pays 100$ more on the water bill than mike, mike has to pay that 100$ back on the rent which also subtracts 100$ off the rent from patti.

My current [code](http://pastebin.com/hAeNvaeW) results in this:

[image]

As you can see it doesn't update the rent textboxes properly. I have been trying to do this for a little over half a day, and I just can't see what I am doing wrong or what might be wrong with my math. Here is all of the code for my textboxes' textchanged events

```
    private void txtMikeWater_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        double num;
        bool parse = Double.TryParse(txtMikeWater.Text, out num);
        if (txtMikeWater.Focused == true)
            if (parse && num >= 0 && num <= expenses[2])
                txtPattiWater.Text = (expenses[2] - num).ToString();
            else
                textBoxValidator(txtMikeWater, expenses[2], 0);

        double difference = Math.Abs(num - Convert.ToDouble(txtPattiWater.Text)) / 2;
        if (num > Convert.ToDouble(txtPattiWater.Text))
        {
            txtPattiRent.Text = ((expenses[0] / 2) + difference).ToString();
            txtMikeRent.Text = ((expenses[0] / 2) - difference).ToString();
        }
        else
            txtPattiRent.Text = ((expenses[0] / 2) - difference).ToString();
            txtMikeRent.Text = ((expenses[0] / 2) + difference).ToString();
    }

    private void txtMikeElectric_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        double num;
        bool parse = Double.TryParse(txtMikeElectric.Text, out num);
        if (txtMikeElectric.Focused)
            if (parse && num >= 0 && num <= expenses[3])
                txtPattiElectric.Text = (expenses[3] - num).ToString();
        double difference = Math.Abs(num - Convert.ToDouble(txtPattiElectric.Text)) / 2;


        if (num > Convert.ToDouble(txtPattiElectric.Text))
        {
            txtPattiRent.Text = ((expenses[0] / 2) + difference).ToString();
            txtMikeRent.Text = ((expenses[0] / 2) - difference).ToString();
        }
        else if (num < Convert.ToDouble(txtPattiElectric.Text))
        {
            txtPattiRent.Text = ((expenses[0] / 2) - difference).ToString();
            txtMikeRent.Text = ((expenses[0] / 2) + difference).ToString();
        }
    }

    private void txtMikeInternet_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {


        double num;
        bool parse = Double.TryParse(txtMikeInternet.Text, out num);
        if (txtMikeInternet.Focused)
            if (parse && num >= 0 && num <= expenses[1])
                txtPattiInternet.Text = (expenses[1] - num).ToString();
        double difference = Math.Abs(num - Convert.ToDouble(txtPattiInternet.Text)) / 2;


        if (num > Convert.ToDouble(txtPattiInternet.Text))
        {
            txtPattiRent.Text = ((expenses[0] / 2) + difference).ToString();
            txtMikeRent.Text = ((expenses[0] / 2) - difference).ToString();
        }
        else if (num < Convert.ToDouble(txtPattiInternet.Text))
        {
            txtPattiRent.Text = ((expenses[0] / 2) - difference).ToString();
            txtMikeRent.Text = ((expenses[0] / 2) + difference).ToString();
        }
    }

    private void txtPattiWater_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        double num;
        bool parse = Double.TryParse(txtPattiWater.Text, out num);
        if (txtPattiWater.Focused == true)
            if (parse && num >= 0 && num <= expenses[2])
                txtMikeWater.Text = (expenses[2] - num).ToString();
        double difference = Math.Abs(num - Convert.ToDouble(txtMikeWater.Text)) / 2;


        if (num < Convert.ToDouble(txtMikeWater.Text))
        {
            txtPattiRent.Text = ((expenses[0] / 2) + difference).ToString();
            txtMikeRent.Text = ((expenses[0] / 2) - difference).ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            txtPattiRent.Text = ((expenses[0] / 2) - difference).ToString();
            txtMikeRent.Text = ((expenses[0] / 2) + difference).ToString();
        }

    }

    private void txtPattiElectric_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {

        double num;
        bool parse = Double.TryParse(txtPattiElectric.Text, out num);
        if (txtPattiElectric.Focused)
            if (parse && num >= 0 && num <= expenses[3])
                txtMikeElectric.Text = (expenses[3] - num).ToString();
        double difference = Math.Abs(num - Convert.ToDouble(txtMikeElectric.Text)) / 2;
        if (num < Convert.ToDouble(txtMikeElectric.Text))
        {
            txtPattiRent.Text = ((expenses[0] / 2) + difference).ToString();
            txtMikeRent.Text = ((expenses[0] / 2) - difference).ToString();
        }
        else if (num > Convert.ToDouble(txtMikeElectric.Text))
        {
            txtPattiRent.Text = ((expenses[0] / 2) - difference).ToString();
            txtMikeRent.Text = ((expenses[0] / 2) + difference).ToString();
        }
    }

    private void txtPattiInternet_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        double num;
        bool parse = Double.TryParse(txtPattiInternet.Text, out num);
        if (txtPattiInternet.Focused)

            if (parse && num >= 0 && num <= expenses[1])
                txtMikeInternet.Text = (expenses[1] - num).ToString();

        double difference = Math.Abs(num - Convert.ToDouble(txtMikeWater.Text)) / 2;
        if (num < Convert.ToDouble(txtMikeWater.Text))
        {
            txtPattiRent.Text = ((expenses[0] / 2) + difference).ToString();
            txtMikeRent.Text = ((expenses[0] / 2) - difference).ToString();
        }
        else if (num > Convert.ToDouble(txtMikeWater.Text))
        {
            txtPattiRent.Text = ((expenses[0] / 2) - difference).ToString();
            txtMikeRent.Text = ((expenses[0] / 2) + difference).ToString();
        }

    }
```

The `expenses` variable just stores the sum the pairs of the textboxes are supposed to have.

If anyone can please help I would appreciate it.

**EDIT** Just for some more clarity regarding the expenses variable.

> ```
> expenses[0] = total rent 
> expenses[1] = total internet 
> expenses[2] = total water
> expenses[3] = total electricity
> ```

Comment: Well, as a programmer I prefer to see your code not your fancy animation (kudos for the effort though)

Comment: I put it in a pastebin because it would take up the whole post lol

Comment: Agreed, kudos for effort.  I recommend you put the code inline rather than at a third party site, so the question is self-contained.

Comment: okay I decided to just paste the code in haha :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks like your rent recalculations are only changing based on the difference of a *single* expense, not the total difference of all of them aggregated.

I suggest you create a single `UpdateRent()` method which sums up the *total* expenses paid for each person then calculates the difference:

```
private void txtPattiElectric_TextChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    double num;
    bool parse = Double.TryParse(txtPattiElectric.Text, out num);
    if (txtPattiElectric.Focused)
        if (parse && num >= 0 && num <= expenses[3])
            txtMikeElectric.Text = (expenses[3] - num).ToString();

    UpdateRent();
}
```

Your rent calculation might look like:

```
private void UpdateRent()
{
    double pattiPaid = GetPattiWater() + GetPattiElectric() + GetPattiInternet();
    double mikePaid = GetMikeWater() + GetMikeElectric() + GetMikeInternet();

    double difference = pattiPaid - mikePaid;
    double baseRent = GetRequiredMonthlyRent() / 2;

    double pattiRent = baseRent - difference;
    double mikeRent = baseRent + difference;

    txtPattiRent.Text = pattiRent.ToString();
    txtMikeRent.Text = mikeRent.ToString();
}
```

I also suggest you move most of the parsing/handling code to helper methods (indicated above) just to make it easier to track and debug the logic in general.

EDIT: Also note that the code eliminates the checking to see who paid more. It all works out in the math. For example, if Mike paid more, then `difference` is negative. Then that negative number is "subtracted" from Patti's base rent effectively increasing it. Feel free to re-introduce `if` checks to do the same work if you find it makes your code easier to understand, debug, and maintain.

EDITx2: It wasn't very clear in my original answer. Methods like `GetPattiWater()` and `GetRequiredMonthlyRent()` should simply read/return the current value:

```
private double GetPattiWater()
{
    double amount;
    Double.TryParse(txtPattiWater.Text, out amount);
    return amount;
}

private double GetRequiredMonthlyRent()
{
    return expenses[3];
}
```

You may need to do some special handling for temporary/blank/invalid non-parseable input in the text fields (the above would just return 0) but it might be simpler just to treat it as zero temporarily.

Comment: So I tried everything you suggested (inluding seperate parse methods) but now the rent textboxes don't even out at all

Comment: in fact one is negative http://gyazo.com/8a182388f5916d6d419fef9c58e68e95 i set mikewater to 250 which should change mikes rent to 425 and pattis rent to 575 instead patti's is 149.5 and mike's is -150.5

Comment: thanks so much for the help though haha i have been needing it really bad

Comment: @IanLundberg: Did you manage to get it working? Perhaps there was a logical oversight in my code or I didn't quite understand what your expected input/outputs were.

Comment: Nope :/ I am still working on it, but I am not sure what is causing it to do it.

Comment: in case you didn't understand though it's supposed to take whatever one person doesn't pay on one bill, and add it their rent making the other person pay less rent for the month so If rent costs 1000$, they pay 500$ each, and if internet is 100$ they pay 50$ each. So if one person can't pay the 50$ for the internet, say they can pay 40$. the 10$ they didn't pay gets added to their rent cost, and subtracted from the other persons rent cost since they had to pay more for the internet that month. does that make better sense? :D

Comment: Also for your second edit, that is what I did :) but I do believe I may have found an erorr in my code so it might not be yours

Comment: @IanLundberg: Yup, total sense. That's how I interpreted your requirements as well. I edited my post making sure it was clear with my intentions of the basic methods. I recommend you continue simplifying your logic and running it through the debugger with breakpoints. Go line by line validating your inputs and expected outputs. Once the logical flow or values deviate from what you expected, then you can narrow down and diagnose the root problems.

Comment: I honestly can't figure it out. I got it so they aren't negative anymore but somehow the sum of the rent turns out to be pattiPaid + mikePaid + the total rent cost. which is 2050 in this case

Comment: I even tested out your math on paper and it works great! but i don't know what is going on here to screw it up

Comment: I figured it out.. I was using the wrong array index for the total haha

Comment: @IanLundberg: Glad to hear it! If you haven't already, try using Visual Studio's debugging features (http://www.dotnetperls.com/debugging, http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/79508/Mastering-Debugging-in-Visual-Studio-A-Beginn) That should help you diagnose bugs. EDIT: Also, now that you've been bitten by the code smell of storing all your unrelated values in an `expenses` array, try instead making a simple class to house those values with nicely named properties instead!